# Ending of Mirzapur

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, mirzapur

Can someone explain the ending of [Mirzapur](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6473300/).

Who is the character at the end scene cutting his hair taking an oath? Why is he relevant now?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character in the end is [Sharad](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm2776317/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t34) [image: Sharad]

[Sharad](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm2776317/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t34) was the son of [Rati Shankar Shukla](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm8981894/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t18).

[Rati Shankar Shukla](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm8981894/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t18) was killed by [Guddu](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm3170495/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t2) who was working for [Kaleen Bhaiya (Akhanda Tripathi)](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm2690647/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t1).

[image: Guddu killing Rati Shankar Shukla] After his father's death he was pledging to take revenge.

It was a perfect ending leading to a lot of possibilities for Season 2 of Mirzapur as now there will be multiple rivalries.

1. [Guddu](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm3170495/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t2) against Tripathi family as [Munna Tripathi](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm4450033/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t4) killed [Sweety](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm6798708/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t7) and [Bablu](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm5750828/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t3).
2. [Sharad](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm2776317/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t34) against Tripathi family as now he wants to complete his father's wish to have Mirzapur.
3. [Sharad](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm2776317/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t34) against [Guddu](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm3170495/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t2) as [Guddu](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm3170495/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t2) killed his father.

Now in this hatred triangle provides a lot of possibilities of teaming up against each other which might be plot of season 2 of Mirzapur.

Answer (score 3):

In the end, the person who is cutting his hair is **"SHARAD"**, son of **"Rati Shankar Shukla"** who has been thrown out of Mirzapur and later killed by Guddu pandit..

It has a major relevance at the end of the series signifying that he will make a entry into politics (which he didn't wanted to, in the first place) of ultimately take revenge of his father death.

Moreover, the makers of Mirzapur marketed the show as

> **Mirzapur - Dimak aur Gun dono Chalegi**

It signifies Guddu pandit's Gun and Bablu pandit's Brain. But in the last episode, Bablu pandit is killed by Munna Tripathi. Hence, Sharad is idle choice to replace him as he is also shown to be a intellectual person which make the relevance more pronounced.

Comment: You gave a point of view on `Mirzapur - Dimak aur Gun dono Chalegi` for season 2 which is quite interesting.

Comment: He was killed by guddu not bablu

Comment: I don't think Sharad will partner with Guddu, especially because Guddu killed Rati Shankar

Comment: @paras I agree, most probably that would be the case. I am only contemplating that the intellectual element of the story will be replaced by sharad. How the associations of different characters turn out will be an interesting thing to watch.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the above explanations, Sharad is an intellectual, so there are sure chances of joining any one side against the other then at the right time own Mirzapur's hold avenging his father's death. That's how politics work...
Sharad's chances of joining hands with Tripathi are greater because there was an agreement between Rati Shukla and Kaleen bhayya not to create violence against each other.